# NHibernate manter dois Mapping para um único objeto

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

eu gostaria de manter dois mappings diferentes para um único objeto é possível fazer isso com NHibernate?

Comment: você está utilizando o fluent-nhibernate? e tem como colocar um exemplo minimo?

Comment: Sim, estou utilizando o Fluent, o grande problema esta acontecendo pois preciso manter conexão com 3 bancos de dados, então pensei em criar um único objeto para todos eles, e criar um mapping para cada banco, o problema é que isso não esta funcionando bem, ele se perde e usa o mapping errado para o banco. Vou tentar providenciar um exemplo para ilustrar melhor